# Python raw json string serialization

Tags: python, json, serialization

i have a dictionary in python with one string variable like below (Of Course there are many other string fields there in the json, but only few are json escaped strings)

```
obj_dict = dict(details="{\"name\":\"Vyshakh\",\"martial_status\" : \"Single\"}")
```

how can I convert such an object to normal json as below:

```
{
   details : {
       name : "Vyshakh",
       martial_status : "Single"
   }
}
```

In Java using Jackson I can annotate a field using @JsonRawValue, what is the best way in Python to achieve the same

Answer (score 2):

Override the encoder to return the raw json string.

```python
import json

class RawJSON(str): pass

origEnc = json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii
def rawEnc(obj):
  if isinstance(obj, RawJSON):
    return obj
  return origEnc(obj)
json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = rawEnc

obj_dict = dict(details=RawJSON("{\"name\":\"Vyshakh\",\"martial_status\" : \"Single\"}"))
print(json.dumps(obj_dict)) # {"details": {"name":"Vyshakh","martial_status" : "Single"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json` module from the standard library has `json.loads()` for this.

You pass the JSON-compatible string to `json.loads()` and it will return a dictionary object.

From the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import json
>>> help(json.loads)
Help on function loads in module json:

loads(s, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)
    Deserialize ``s`` (a ``str`` instance containing a JSON
    document) to a Python object.
```

Comment: I know i can use json.loads(), but wich parse through the entire string and create a dictionary out of it. But in reality , there is no use for the data for the resource owner, only for external systems this data is relevant. I worry why i should convert this string to another dictionary object, and this object is very heavy in size can go up to 128KB of string data. is there a way that while serialization, just consider this as a raw Json formated string. that is what @JsonRawValue does in Java (Jackson)..Looking for any alternative like that in python