# Include json fragments when serialising json in python

Tags: python, json

I'm working with a large collections of json objects coming from a database, and I would like to wrap these fragments with an additional metadata before serving them through a REST api.

Imagine having millions of records roughly looking like::

```
'{"key": "value", "another key": "another_value", ...}'
```

I am trying very hard to avoid deserialising these fragments into python dicts only to serialise them again, but effectively my response will look like::

```
  {
    "count": n,
    "status": "success",
    "rows: [
      {"key": "value", "another key": "another_value", ...},
      {"key": "value", "another key": "another_value", ...},
      ...
      {"key": "value", "another key": "another_value", ...}
    ]
  }
```

I could not find anything in the python json module that would allow me to reuse json fragments without having to load them into dicts.  The `JSONEncoder` only seems to care about converting the objects into serialisable objects, rather than allow me to control the serialisation aspects.  I'm open to using json libraries outside the stdlib but I would rather avoiding writing my own string template for serialisiation, as the example above is simplified version of the data.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do that. Something seems wrong if your database is giving you JSON fragments as strings, anyway.

Comment: Skip the JSON part & construct your whole response from string & templating

Comment: You could probably wrap the existing JSON string in a custom object, and customise the JSON encoder to recognise that custom class and use its string as is…

Comment: @deceze could you put an example showing that?  I cannot see a way in the JSONEncoder to preserve a string attribute as is without escaping all the json syntax!

Comment: The stock `json` module's encoder is implemented in C, so there is no way even with hacky subclassing to make it do what you want. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f0eafa844bf5a380603d55e8d4b42d8c2a3439d/Lib/json/encoder.py#L249 A simple hack would be to encode a magic string like `"__ROWS__"` instead, and replace that with string substitution after `json.dumps`.

Comment: This is what I had in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48985560/476

Comment: @Thomas Parts of `JSONEncoder` are still implemented in Python, exactly the part you link to, and it can be customised to some useful extent.